# How to copy the contents of a cell/several cells (as text) in order to add it to the existing text in another cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My problem is actually rather simply, I can‘t seem to get to a solution though.

E.g.

In Cell A I have the text „Apples“

In the cells B C and D I have the text

```
B = „Bananas“
C = „Pears“
D = „Grapes“
```

I want to select the cells B, C and D and paste them into A in order to get

```
A = „Apples, Bananas, Pears, Grapes“
```

Both Cell A and the Cells B, C and D change so I cannot concatenate / use a simple concatenation function like concatenate A & B & C & D.

The function should be similar to clicking into the respective cell , for example B, select the word, press CTRL + C, the click into cell A , put the cursor behind „Apples“ and press CTRL + V.

I searched for my above mentioned question, but only found something about copying the content of several cells as text to the clipboard by using Data Objects.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thank you!

————

A simple attempt on my side was to copy the range into a word doc , select all the contents in the word doc, copy that and subsequently paste it into the cell

```
Option Explicit 

Sub CopyInCell() 

 Sheets("Sheet1").Activate 
 With Selection.Interior 
  .Pattern = xlSolid 
  .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic 
  .Color = 5287936 
  .TintAndShade = 0 
  .PatternTintAndShade = 0 
 End With 
 Selection.Copy 
 Windows("Sheet2").Activate 
 SendKeys "{F2}", True 
 Application.SendKeys ("%~"), True 
 Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True 
End Sub
```

Nest step would be to automate/make the pasting work in a way that I can simply select a cell where the pasted text should be added to the end of the cells text.

---

Attempt at using Pehs method combined with Switching workbooks

```
Sub insert_change()

 Dim Concatenated As String
 Dim Cell As Range
 Dim Cell2 As Range
 For Each Cell In Selection.Cells 'go through all cells within the selection
     If Concatenated = vbNullString Then
         Concatenated = Cell.Value 
     Else
         Concatenated = Concatenated & ", " & Cell.Value 
     End If
 Next Cell
 Windows("Book2.xlsx").Activate
 Sheets("A").Activate
 Cell2 = Selection.Cells.Value
 Concatenated = Cell2 & ", " & Concatenated
 Selection.Cells.Value = Concatenated
```

End Sub

Results is a runtime error 13,types not matching,  in line

```
Cell2 = Selection.Cells.Value
```

What could be the reason for that?
When I switch manually to that Sheet I have the right cell selected.

Thanks!

Comment: This `Debug.Print Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Selection.Value), ", ")` should help you to figure out the rest. Try something on your own, then come back with the code you have and tell which errors you get or where you got stuck.

Comment: Hi Peh! Thanks for the answer, will have a look at this worksheet function! Will add the results as soon as i have them

Comment: Hi Peh. Had a look at the Debug.Print function. But all I could find was that this immeadiate window can be used to directly execute code, get/set values directly,get information about the workbook, let results of a macro be printed to it. I don’t see how I could use it in my case. I changed my approach/code and found sort of a solution.

Comment: Well `Debug.Print` was just an example to visualize the result of the `Join`. This was just a hint for you into the right direction. Although using `SendKeys` is the worst solution you can imagine for this task. Please don't do that. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your cells are all in one column and continuously (no blank cells in between) you can just use:

```
Selection.Cells(1).Value = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Selection.Value), ", ")
```

Alternatively if they are not continuously or in a row you can use the following:

```
Dim Concatenated As String
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Selection.Cells 'go through all cells within the selection
    If Concatenated = vbNullString Then
        Concatenated = Cell.Value 'collect the first value
    Else
        Concatenated = Concatenated & ", " & Cell.Value 'concatenate all other values comma separated
    End If
Next Cell

Selection.Cells(1).Value = Concatenated 'write the concatenated string into the first cell of the selection
```

Note that you will have to select **all** cells A, B, C and D and then run the macro. It will write the result into cell A then.

---

Alternatively to write/append it into another workbooks cell, use the following instead of the last line above.

```
Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("A").Activate 'workbook and worksheet to select from

Dim AppendRange As Range
On Error Resume Next 'if next line throws error then no range was selected
Set AppendRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the destination cell to append", Title:="Select", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not AppendRange Is Nothing Then
    If AppendRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then 'check if more than one cell was selected
        MsgBox "Only selection of one destination cell is allowed.", vbCritical, "Cannot append"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    AppendRange.Value = AppendRange.Value & IIf(AppendRange.Value <> vbNullString, ", ", vbNullString) & Concatenated
End If
```

If you use this alternative you would need to select the cells of the source worksheet first, then start the macro. It will ask the user which will be the destination cell and then concatenate all values to the destination.

Comment: Hi Peh! Thanks for the extensive help! I tried to add the function to change the workbook and concatenating the selected cells on workbook 1 with the final cell on workbook 2.Unfortunately my attempts failed.   I added the not working code in my question.

Comment: Since you cannot select cells on multiple workbooks/worksheets at once you will need to ask the user to select a destination cell. See my improved answer above.